# How to compressed file in Minio (Spring, Docker)

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, compression, minio

I have a Spring project that runs in Docker, back, web are launched through the docker-compose file, minio is also there, I don't know how to set up compression, I tried all the different options, it doesn't work. Please help)

This is my Docker-compose file

```
environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: miniominio
      MINIO_COMPRESS: on
      MINIO_COMPRESS_EXTENSIONS:
      MINIO_COMPRESS_MIME_TYPES:
```

or it might be worth placing compression in the application.propert.yml

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remove the env vars and enable it through the configuration through mc. If your cluster is set up as `myminio` in mc:

`mc admin config set myminio compression enable=on allow_encryption=off extensions= mime_types=`

The configuration will be stored on your cluster. Note that if you have encryption enabled, you need to enable this separately as well.

Compression is fully transparent, so it requires manual inspection of backend files to see if it is correctly applied.